# In Robot Framework, screenshots are not linked to log.html when executed via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I have setup Robot framework execution via Jenkins. The job is setup and executed successfully. The screenshots are also getting captured. 
But the only issue is that in the file log.html the screenshots are not referenced i.e whenever there is a failures, the log.html says that a screenshot has been captured but the name of the screenshot is not mentioned also the screenshot is not opened inline. Refer below example:

[image]

Above is a screenshot of log.html where upon failure the log says that the screenshot is captured but no file name is mentioned. When the complete test-suite executes there are more than 1000 screenshot in the result folder and it is very difficult to identify which screenshot belongs to which failure.

Following is my jenkins configuration:

[image]

Comment: This is weird, the keyword itself should take a screenshot and embeds it into the log file (it even says so in the log). I'd start exploring in these areas: are the screenshots really available? Haven't you by mistake moved the screenshots into a different directory? Isn't it something with Jenkins and its integration that prevents you from seeing the screenshots? What about a browser, isn't the problem there? A quick trick could be to use `Screenshot` library and see if it helps (https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Screenshot.html).

Comment: I suspect that Jenkins is finding the output, log and report files but not the *.png files, because is in a different folder. Please try to change to `**/*.png`.

Comment: @Helio this did not work. all the screenshots are in the same folder as log.html

Comment: @pavelsaman Yes the screenshots are available and are in the same directory. I can view the screenshots. .

Comment: @pavelsaman any update on this??

Comment: @Shaveta: Do you have? If so, please update your question or even add an answer if you solved it. I guess you need to explore it and find out on your own, it seems users here can't solve it with what we know about your problem.

Comment: @pavelsaman, I have not been able to solve it as of now. I will work on it and update here..

Comment: @S.C Did you figure out a way? This is still happening for me with proper setup.

Comment: Here is the answer, it works for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73438453/image-doesnt-show-in-html-file-in-the-jenkins-workspace

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for but using this keyword embeds image directly in your log.

```
Capture Page Screenshot     EMBED
```