# Robot Framework Browser Library screenshots are not nested in log although being copied by RobotPublisher in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, png, robotframework, screenshot

- Jenkins 2.386
- Pipeline plugin 590.v6a_d052e5a_a_b_5
- Robot Framework plugin 3.3.0
- Python3.9.2
- robotframework 6.0.2
- robotframework-assertion-engine 1.0.0
- robotframework-browser 15.1.0
- robotframework-pythonlibcore 4.0.0

[Screenshots are not nested in log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjskw.png)

[Robot Publisher copies results to specific build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMbDh.png)

[Using "otherFiles" option copies PNG images and Browser Library directories structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL1KS.png)

Clicking the icon of missing image in Robot log redirects to screenshot properly.

I work on Jenkins master node - I don't use slaves.

Here is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh 'robot -d results Scripts/My_Test_Suite.robot'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Results') {
            steps {
                step([
                    $class: 'RobotPublisher',
                    outputPath: 'results',
                    outputFileName: '*.xml',
                    otherFiles: '**/*.png',
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Before I faced described problem I configured CSP just like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37524992/6639428.
That means I used following configuration and according to https://content-security-policy.com/img-src/ it should work, but it doesn't...

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP","sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self' data: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ;")
```

Comment: I have faint recollection having similar issues *with* jenkins and the root cause was CSRF blocking inline images and nothing to do with robot .. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/csrf-protection/

Comment: I've tried with CSRF and CSP configuration but nothing helps. I made a workaround using RFW Browser Library EMBED screenshots. That's enough for now, but the logs are much larger in size, so I guess I'll have to troubleshoot this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `--artifacts png --artifactsinsubfolders`  this copies the screenshot for particular tests.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I'm not sure about this solution. I didn't try it yet because it's an option from pabot, which I don't use, but this line `otherFiles: '**/*.png',` in RobotPublisher successfully copies png files from subfolders (check the linked screens in description).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem that the screen shot does not show up in log.html and it is not clickable. Check the console log: 403 Forbidden, strict-origin-when-cross-origin.

I followed [Image doesn't show in html file in the Jenkins workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73438453/image-doesnt-show-in-html-file-in-the-jenkins-workspace)

Now the Jenkins images can show in log.html

Another way is to upload all log.html/report.html and png files to 3rd web server.